# Handle uploaded file buffer by buffer on the fly?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to receive an uploaded file in Python in a way that it doesn't have to be fully received while I'm performing processing on it?

Comment: Are you using sockets? The answer very much depends on the way you are actually receiving the file.

Comment: @JaronThatcher: I mentioned that it's Django. Any solution that would actually get me there would be good.

Comment: I actually missed the Django tag, my bad. I'm not sure how Django does file uploads. I'm assuming that it would use a socket at a low level, but it may be the case that you don't have a handle to that socket.

If you were manually doing this using a [socket.recv call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv), then you would be able to specify the size that you want to receive at a time, then loop over that and perform logic on it.

I am thinking that this is a little too low level to be a proper solution, but could theoretically work if Django has no other way.